# trying to get json object from php to android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

i am trying to parse an array from my php script to my android app. 
my android  code

```
public void func4(View view)throws Exception
{final String TAG_CONTACTS = "response";
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
    rp.put("pLat", "SELECT officer_name FROM iwmp_officer");

    client.post("http://10.0.2.2/conc3.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        public final void onSuccess(String response) {
            // handle your response here
            ArrayList<String> User_List = new ArrayList<String>();


            try
        {
      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
       // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
      for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
      {
          JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);



         User_List.add(json_data.getString(TAG_CONTACTS));
         String s = User_List.get(0).toString();
         tx.setText(s);
      }

         } 
            catch (Exception e)
        {
                tx.setText((CharSequence) e);
         }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
            // something went wrong
            tx.setText(response);
        }               
    });
}
```

now i am sending or ECHOing a jSON array from my php code, which is being read into the response object of string type.

`<?php
       $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
       $arrlength=count($cars);
       echo json_encode($cars); 
        exit;
     ?>`

now error i am getting is ***org.json.JSONException: Value Volvo at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject***

i think thar onSuccess func accept string parameter and i m sending json as a parameter to it.. thats what causing problem please help.

Comment: What does the exception tell you? That you're appying a fuction which tries to find a JSON object where there's really a String value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

> ```
>     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_contact, "GET", params);
>          Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
>          try {
>              int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>              if (success == 1) {
>                  groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>                  System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>                  for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>                  JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>                  String name = c.getString(TAG_CONTACTS);
>                  System.out.println("Checking ::"+name);
>              namelist.add(name); // namelist is ur arraylist
>                  }
>              }else {            
>                  showAlert();
>              }
>          } catch (JSONException e) {
>              e.printStackTrace();
>          }
>          return null;
> ```

Let me know ur problem solved or not...

Comment: You should note the source of external or third-party classes or APIs! JSONParser class (synonymously): androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Answer found, i guess i was trying to convert an already String converted object from json into string again. 
well to be precise i ust deleted  **JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);**
and it worked for me. Now i am able to save all values in my array.